# How to update dataframe value in multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I want to update pandas

Hello, I want to compare the speeds of single-core and multicore in pandas dataframe calculations. 
The following cases are given, The column'c' in the 'i'th-row is the average of the values ​​of 'a' from 'i-9'-row to 'i'th-row.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array, Manager
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time 

total_num = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,total_num*2+1).reshape(total_num,2),
              columns=['a','b'])
df['c']=0


df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,total_num*2+1).reshape(total_num,2),
              columns=['a','b'])
df2['c']=0


def Cal(start, end):
    for i in range(end-start-1):
        if i+start < 10:
            df.loc[i+start,'c']=df.loc[:i+start,'c'].mean()
        else :
            df.loc[i+start,'c']=df.loc[i-9:i+start,'c'].mean()

def Cal2(my_df,start, end):
    for i in range(end-start-1):
        if i+start < 10:
            my_df.df.loc[i+start,'c']=my_df.df.loc[:i+start,'c'].mean()
        else :
            my_df.df.loc[i+start,'c']=my_df.df.loc[i-9:i+start,'c'].mean()
    print(my_df)

print('Single core : --->')
start_t = time.time()

Cal(0,total_num+1)

end_t = time.time()
print(end_t-start_t)

print('Multiprocess ---->')

if __name__=='__main__':
    num=len(df2)
    num_core=4 
    between=num//num_core

    mgr=Manager()
    ns = mgr.Namespace()
    ns.df=df2
    procs=[]

    start_t =time.time()

    for index in range(num_core):
        proc=Process(target=Cal2,args=(ns,index*between,(index+1)*between))
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()

    end_t = time.time()
    print(end_t-start_t)
```

At first I realized that Multiprocessing does not use global variables. So I used Manager. However, the 'c'column of df2 did not change.

How do I do what I want to do? :p

Comment: This does not look like a good idea. Just take the mean of multiple columns with `df.loc[:10, 'd'].mean()` and `df.loc[10:, 'd'].mean()`

Answer (score 0):

You may look at [swifter](https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter) as well, iit applies functions using multiprocessing **IF it helps in faster code execution**.

**In your case it is a terrible idea**, 10 is a really small amount of data so distributing it between cores will not help and cost of processes will be much higher than operations.

Furthermore, memory sharing is not a good idea between processes (as this is really costly), and that's what you are trying to do here (usually you split data beforehand and push it to multiprocessing functions like `applymap`, but once again, data chunks should be much bigger).

You could use `threads`, as those are the ones you may be after, but remember about Python's [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) (you may read about threads, processes and GIL in other answers, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python))